# How to join/sort two related data sets without ID?

Tags: r, merge

I would like to combine two data frames which are related but have no common ID.

Example data:

```
 df1                 df2
2010-01-01           2010-01-26
2010-01-02           2010-01-27
2010-01-03           2010-01-28
2010-01-25           2010-01-29
                     2010-01-30
                     (2010-01-31)
```

Desired:

```
2010-01-01
2010-01-02
2010-01-03     
2010-01-25 
2010-01-26
2010-01-27
2010-01-28
2010-01-29
2010-01-30
```

I tried the

```
library(plyr) # joining tables
hi<-join(df1, df2, by = NULL)
```

But doesnt work without an identifier.

Comment: Try `rbind` or `rbind.fill` (the latter is from `plyr`).

Comment: @Mamba Before you do `rbind` (as commented by krlmlr), make sure that the colnames (assuming there is only one colum) are the same for the datasets.

Comment: If you want the dates to be in ascending order, you could then use `order` after `rbind`. That would give the desired format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rbind` does exactly what you want: It literally "stacks" the columns above each other:

```
df1 <- data.frame(data=c("2010-01-01", "2010-01-02", "2010-01-03", "2010-01-25"))
df2 <- data.frame(data=c("2010-01-26", "2010-01-27", "2010-01-28", "2010-01-29", "2010-01-30"))

rbind(df1, df2)
#        data
#1 2010-01-01
#2 2010-01-02
#3 2010-01-03
#4 2010-01-25
#5 2010-01-26
#6 2010-01-27
#7 2010-01-28
#8 2010-01-29
```

In case one of your dataframe has more columns than the other, use `rbind.fill` from the `plyr` package to fill up the missing values with `NA`.

```
require(plyr)
df1$test <- sample(nrow(df1))
rbind.fill(df1, df2)
#        data test
#1 2010-01-01    3
#2 2010-01-02    1
#3 2010-01-03    2
#4 2010-01-25    4
#5 2010-01-26   NA
#6 2010-01-27   NA
#7 2010-01-28   NA
#8 2010-01-29   NA
#9 2010-01-30   NA
```